# System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer Handling Of Numbers

Tags: .net, text-to-speech, speech, speech-synthesis

Sometimes I have a number like #12543 and I want the synthesizer to say "Number one-two-five-four-three".

Other times I would like the synthesizer to say "Number twelve-thousand-five-hundred-fourty-three".

Does anybody here know what mechanism in System.Speech regulates the pronunciation of these numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [`SayAs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.sayas(v=vs.110).aspx) Enumeration and the [`AppendTextWithHint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms586842(v=vs.110).aspx) Method, this example is based on the Microsoft documentation.

```
using System;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;

namespace ConsoleApplication66
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
            synth.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            PromptBuilder talk = new PromptBuilder();
            talk.AppendText("#12543");
            talk.AppendTextWithHint("#12543", SayAs.SpellOut);
            talk.AppendTextWithHint("#12543", SayAs.NumberOrdinal);
            talk.AppendTextWithHint("#12543", SayAs.NumberCardinal);
            synth.Speak(talk);

        }
    }
}
```